# Making lists of nearby points using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, distance, routing

I am a new user of QGIS. I have uploaded a csv file to my QGIS map with 500 points and I want to make sets of 10 points (or different amount of points) based on distance.

I want to gather nearby points (based on meter linear distance) grouped by 10 points and have one excel or csv file per set of points (of course each list should not include any of the other points already on another set). Is this possible?

And also if there were 501 points, is there a way to make 1 set of 11 points and the rest of 10 points? I am just using the example of sets of 10 but it would be great to choose any number for the set of points (like lists of 5, 20, 50 points or whatever).

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE Ignacio. What have you tried so far? Have you done any research? Are you aware, that sometimes your parameters might not add up, by being too many/few points within the set distance?

Comment: QGIS has several point clustering algorithms in the Processing Toolbox. If they don't meet your needs, please [edit] your question and explain what methods you tried, and what you still need to achieve.